# Getting Error "HWCSEC6010E: Error in checking permitted service actions. " while connecting IBM Cloud DB2

Tags: python, db2, ibm-cloud, coursera-api

I am getting Error while connecting to IBM DB2 on cloud, When I click on "Go to UI":

[image]

Getting following error:

> HWCSEC6010E: Error in checking permitted service actions

Following is the Logs:

[image]

Comment: Copy-pasted error reports are preferred to images of error reports as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553)

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue at IBM. I contected their support, they are aware of the issue and are investigating it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error too on different browsers. I think there is an issue at IBM cloud service itself.

Comment: This suites more of a comment than an answer. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ankita! I ran into the same problem while trying to do the IBM Data Science Capstone activity (Coursera). I just saw this message on the IBM website:

"Updated 1/18/2022 IBM is actively responding to the reported remote code execution vulnerability in the Apache Log4j 2 Java library dubbed Log4Shell (or LogJam). We are investigating and taking action for IBM as an enterprise, IBM products and IBM services that may be potentially impacted, and will continually publish information to help customers detect, investigate and mitigate attacks, if any, to their IBM products and services."

I also tried creating a new service and it's not working, it says "Provision in Progress".

I guess it's an IBM issue, not sure what to do now